# Do I have to buy a WordPress plan if I have Bluehost?

Tags: upgrade

I have started a blog through bluehost. Since I've paid for bluehost and connected it to WordPress do I have to buy a WordPress plan as well or can I carry on without it? I was reading through the different things and the Premium WordPress plan says I am able to monetize my site. Will I be able to do this without it or should I upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the self-hosted WordPress software (that Bluehost is hosting for you) and the WordPress.com service. They're not the same thing. You can read about the differences here: https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to pay any Wordpress.com plan. You use the bluehost's Wordpress installer to deploy wordpress in your hosting account. You can monetize your site without any issues after this, as the advertising platforms are independent from wordpress.com